# Stripe Connect API - How Do I Retrieve A Connected Account's Status?

Tags: stripe-payments

I am using Stripe Connect as a platform.  On the **Connected accounts** page on the Stripe dashboard, there is a *STATUS* column.

[image]

How do I retrieve this information via the Connect API?

I am looking at the standard GET / retrieve endpoint for Connect accounts at https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/retrieve, but the response does not include an account status data point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no `status` field on the account object. Those statuses are likely inferred by looking at whether an account has [charges](https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/object#account_object-charges_enabled) and [payouts](https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/object#account_object-payouts_enabled) enabled.

Answer (score 3):

I too faced this problem. I came to understand that we have to check it manually from our side. You can check the status by using below conditions:

```
Account account = Account.retrieve("ACC_ID");
if(account.getRequirements().getPastDue() != null || account.getRequirements().getCurrentlyDue() != null){
//RESTRICTED
}
else if(!account.getPayoutsEnabled() ){
//PENDING
}
else
//COMPLETED
```

You can also check whether transfer and card payment are active or not from Capabilities object.

Answer (score 0):

Stripe response is:

One of the most useful properties to determine the state of a Connected Account is the `requirements`
https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/object#account_object-requirements